# Sidebar (float: left) not always floating left

Tags: html, css

I currently made a container to contain sidebars and content, but when I add more text to the sidebar than to the container the second sidebar floats a bit to the side. These are the code's I'm using.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        Placeholder
        <br><hr>
        Test
    </div>
    <div class="content">Placeholder</div>
    <br>
    <div class="sidebar">Placeholder</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
  width: 222px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #949494;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.content {
  width: 666px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #949494;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.container {
  width: 932px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I am not addressing the question, but I do notice you have two box-shadow declarations in `.content` and `.sidebar`. If you want just want the latter `box-shadow`, then that's fine, but if you are trying to use both, then use this instead. `box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD, 0px 1px 0px #949494;`

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this issue in Firefox 29.0.1. Does it do the same in all browsers, or is it one browser in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using two sidebars with the same class. put a .clear {clear:both} in your css file and use an  jsut before the sidebar closing div. If you really need two sidebars, you have to create another rule for it. sidebar1, sidebar2 with different floats. Change the inline-block to block.

Comment: Worked sort of as I meant, best answer though. Thank you ;D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question:
**HTML**

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            Placeholder
            <br><hr>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="content">Placeholder</div>
        <br>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam iusto eligendi maxime autem debitis eum consectetur odit at exercitationem velit earum sunt nobis laborum. Dignissimos vero accusantium velit rerum voluptatibus?</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
width: 222px;
height: auto;
background-color: #E9E9E9;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #949494;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 5px;
float: left;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.content {
width: 666px;
height: auto;
background-color: #E9E9E9;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #949494;
padding: 5px;
float: right;
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.container {
width: 932px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vfgla)

Answer (score 0):

Update the class .sidebar

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #949494;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 222px;
}
```